# Dynamic textviews not have perfect click listener or touch Listener

Tags: java, android

this is my method to implement number of textview as per the word in sentence. each word have click event  or touch event.

```
static ArrayList<TextView> sentence(String[] arr,
        LinearLayout linelay_wordIn1) {
    if (linelay_wordIn1.getChildCount() > 0)
        linelay_wordIn1.removeAllViews();
    if (allTextView != null) {
        allTextView.remove(txt);
        allTextView.clear();
        System.out.println("hello remove all textview here");
    } else {
        System.out.println("hello all textview array is null here");
    }

    String str1 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str1 = str1 + arr[i].toString();
        System.out.println(" senctence separte in word " + arr[i]
            + " words" + arr.length);
    }
    /* listview for getting textview */

    System.out.println("sentence " + str1.toString() + "str1 length :: "
        + str1.length());
    txt = new TextView[arr.length];
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
   // lp.setMarginStart(arr.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        txt[j] = new TextView(contextG);
        txt[j].setId(j);
        txt[j].setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txt[j].setTextSize(60);
        txt[j].setTypeface(
            Typeface.createFromAsset(contextG.getAssets(), "TIMES.TTF"),
            Typeface.BOLD);
        txt[j].setText(arr[j]);
        txt[j].setLayoutParams(lp);
        txt[j].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt[j].setOnTouchListener(myListner);
        System.out.println("txt[j]" + j + "id " + txt[j].getId());
        allTextView.add(txt[j]); /* add textview into arraylist */
        linelay_wordIn1.addView(txt[j], j);
    }
    return allTextView;

    }
```

my touch Listener code is here

```
public static OnTouchListener myListner = new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     TextView tv = (TextView) v;

    //Layout layout = ((TextView) v).getLayout();
    String str = tv.getText().toString();
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    //if (layout != null) {
    //int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
    //int characterOffset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
    //Log.i("index", "" + characterOffset);
    //}
    System.out.println(" str of sentence :: " + str.toString());

    if (Music.playing()) {
    // do nothing
    } else {
    try {
        /* Music renew for memory leak problems */
        Music.renewMediaPlayer();
        /*--------------------*/
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("I ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio1[0]);
        } else if (str.equals("like ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio1[1]);
        } else if (str.equals("to ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio1[2]);
        } else if (str.equals("ski.")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio1[3]);
        tooltip(tool1, 0, 3, x, y);// tool1 is for guide text
                       // array
                       // and 0
                       // for index
        } else if (str.equals("When ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio2[0]);
        tooltip(tool2, 0, 0, x, y);
        } else if (str.equals("the ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio2[1]);
        tooltip(tool2, 0, 1, x, y);
        } else if (str.equals("snow ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio2[2]);
        tooltip(tool2, 0, 2, x, y);
        } else if (str.equals("falls, ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio2[3]);
        } else if (str.equals("head ")) {
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio2[5]);
        tooltip(tool2, 1, 5, x, y);
        } else if (str.equals("slopes.")) {
        float x1 = event.getX();
        float y1 = event.getY();
        Music.play(contextG, sent_audio2[8]);
        tooltip(tool2, 2, 8, x1, y1);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return true;

}
};
```

here : number words store in string array to set as text in textviews

```
 /* sentence here */
static String[] words1 = { "I ", "like ", "to ", "ski." };
static String[] words2 = { "When ", "the ", "snow ", "falls, ", "I ",
    "head ", "to ", "the ", "slopes." };
static String[] words3 = { "My ", "Children ", "join ", "me ", "on ",
    "the ", "trip ", "to ", "the ", "hills. " };
static String[] words4 = { "We ", "ride ", "in ", "cable ", "cars ", "to ",
    "the ", "top ", "of ", "the ", "hill. " };
static String[] words5 = { "The ", "snow ", "sparkles ", "in ", "the ",
    "sunshine ", "as", "we ", "ski ", "the ", "trails. " };
static String[] words6 = { "I ", "pass ", "many ", "novice ", "skiers ",
    "as ", "they ", "struggle ", "to ", "stay ", "up. " };
static String[] words7 = { "I ", "try ", "to ", "watch ", "out ", "as ",
    "I ", "whiz ", "by. " };
static String[] words8 = { "If ", "I ", "do ", "not, ", "I ", "will ",
    "fall  ", "too. " };
```

here is : one method to show another toast on textview array x and y position on each and every click.

```
static void tooltip(String[] arr, int toolstringindex, int placeindex,
    float x, float y) {
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(contextG);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool_tip_img);

TextView tv = new TextView(contextG);
// set the TextView properties like color, size etc
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv.setTextSize(40);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    Gravity.TOP);
lp.leftMargin = 10;
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

// set the text you want to show in Toast
tv.setText(arr[toolstringindex]);
layout.addView(tv);
// // int[] values = new int[2];
float viewx = allTextView.get(placeindex).getX();
float viewy = allTextView.get(placeindex).getY();
// // int x = values[0];
// // int y = values[1];
System.out.println(" hello  x::" + x + 50 + "y :: " + y);
Toast toast = new Toast(contextG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, (int) x, (int) y - 80);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();

}
```

now actual problem is that x and y position not coming perfectly .its
showing somewhere else on screen so, i didnt get it what to do? if any
one have better idea for this please let me to implement this . some
line of code will be helpful to me.please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: dont creare n TextViews and n listeners, use one listener and find rhe word here

Comment: see TexrView.getLayout() method - Layout class gives you simple api for finding the word at given position

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

to this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
lp.setMargins(x, y, maxX, maxY);
```

the maxX and maxY are irrelevant just set them to text width and height.